# Provide spacing between categories in highcharts while retaining labels

Tags: highcharts

We are trying to provide spacing between the categories used for highcharts but for some reason the x-axis seem so zoomed in that its difficult to navigate.

Tried using maxPadding setting for x-axis but the labels on x-axis are also getting changed.

These are the categories used :

```
categories: [
    '11-20','11-23','11-24','11-25','11-27','11-30','12-01']
}
```

Upon using

```
xAxis: {
    maxPadding: 1
},
```

The spacing looks fine but categories used above are all replaced by 0,0.5,1,... till 12.

Is there any way we can preserve the categories or x-axis labels while reducing spacing between them

Could you please clarify

Thank You

Comment: Looks like the parameter min inside x-axis is causing an issue. The setting is like xAxis: { min : 6 } which is causing the graph zoomed in and focus on last data point position which is 7. Looks like it depends on number of data pointswe would like to have visible when opened.

Comment: Can you make a live example of the problem? If you use a column series, then you can increase pointPadding http://jsfiddle.net/8n039mu3/